# Dealing with the singularity of a complex polynomial in $1/z$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, polynomials, complex-numbers

*Disclaimer: I have virtually no complex analysis knowledge and I am seeking to get up to speed in this area of analysis. At the moment, I am surveying material on elementary complex functions and the related ideas pertaining to their singularities. I apologise if the questions I ask might be incredibly banal or obvious, but I really have very little knowledge in this are and am desperately seeking to better myself therein.*

For $n\in\mathbb N$ and $\{a_n\in\mathbb F:n\in\mathbb N\}$ where $\mathbb F\in\{\mathbb R, \mathbb C\}$ consider the complex polynomial in $\frac{1}z$ given by $f:D(f)\subseteq\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ where $f$ is defined

$$f(z):=\sum_{i=0}^na_nz^{-n}.$$
The domain of $f$, denoted $D(f)$, is clearly the set $\mathbb C/\{0\}$, since $f(z=0)$ is not well defined.

**My question**: is there any way to **extend** $f$ to all of $\mathbb C$? So as to have, for our above $f$, that $D(f)\equiv\mathbb C$? If so, how, precisely, does one go about "plugging in" the point $c=0$? (I have a feeling that this is to do with the notion of a singularity)

Comment: You extend to the Riemann Sphere $C \cup \{\infty\}$ and note $\lim_{z \to 0} \tfrac{1}{z} = \infty$. The Riemann Sphere happening to be the correct one point compactification is quite a powerful tool.

Comment: I see - so for the example of $f$ above we cannot proceed in a manner similar to the function $g(z)=\sin(z)/z$ and "remove the singularity"?

Comment: We are doing precisely that - defining the behavior to remove a singularity. The difference is that $1 \in \mathbb{C}$ while $\infty \not \in \mathbb{C}$ so we must extend to the Riemann Sphere. In practice, much of complex analysis is done with the point $\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is impossible to extend $D(f)$ to include $0$ analytically in $\mathbb{C}$, as $\lim\limits_{z\to0}f(z)=\infty$ where $\infty$ really means that the limit diverges and does not exist. Thus plugging in any value for $f(0)$ leads to a jump discontinuity at $f(z=0)$.

In your comment, $g(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{z}$ is able to be analytically extended as the limit $\lim\limits_{z\to0}f(z)=1$ does exist (in $\mathbb{C}$).